# Feature extraction: optimal sampling

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have a very complex shape, please see the following image. I want to sample this image such that I can use the extracted points and describe the image. In other words, I want to only have those sample rather than the whole points on my image. I know that this topic is related to "feature extraction", but I could not find any specific method discussing an optimal way for extracting the samples.

I want to select the minimum number of points that yield the best representation of my image.

[image]

Comment: Your question is pretty vague and your sample set image is not convincing as we can't see the relation to the input model. (Not counting the fact the the input model is 3D and you want a 2D description, which is not really compatible.)

Comment: The sample is 3D, but for the sake of illustration, I just showed a 2D section. So, those samples are only for the front view.

Comment: Do you mean your points are already detected with an ad-hoc method and you now focus on the selection of the minimal number that will lead to the "best representation"? As well, "the best representation" directly depend on what you want to do with in... Is it to discriminate this shape from another one ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I have no specific method to select those points, but I want to use a method to select the minimum number of them.